# Ghost Blog - Check Request Headers

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, ghost-blog, ghost

I have a self-hosted Ghost blog running. I want to check for the presence of a custom header, for example `X-Den-Was-Here`.

What I want to implement is a conditional check, where:

1. If the header is **present** - load the blog cotnents.
2. If the header is **not present** - return a [401 Unauthorized](https://httpstatuses.com/401).

Where would be the most appropriate place to perform this check within the Ghost infra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution to this (and I am open to have someone validate it and show me that I chose the wrong location for it) is to modify the caching layer to verify an inbound request header.

For that, you need `\core\server\middleware\cache-control.js`. Within the `cacheControlHeaders` function, you can just add the snippet below right before the `next()` call:

```
if (req.headers["den-was-here"] != "1")
{
    return res.sendStatus(401);
}
```

This will effectively throw a **401 Unauthorized** response for any request that does not carry the header.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Express 4.x API Reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get) you can access headers using `req.get(headerName)`, and check if it returns `undefined` or something, e.g.:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.get(headerName) == undefined){
    //do not load modules
  }else{
    loadModules();
  }
});
```

Comment: That, of course, is the way to get the header. My question relates more to the Ghost architecture and where within the flow it would be appropriate to enforce a header check.